# how to load modin dataframe from pyarrow or pandas

Tags: pyarrow, modin

Since Modin does not support loading from multiple pyarrow files on s3, I am using pyarrow to load the data.

```py
    import s3fs
    import modin.pandas as pd
    from pyarrow import parquet
    
    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(
        key=aws_key,
        secret=aws_secret
    )

    table = parquet.ParquetDataset(
        path_or_paths="s3://bucket/path", 
        filesystem=s3,
    ).read(
        columns=["hotelId", "startDate", "endDate"]
    )

    # to get a pandas df the next step would be table.to_pandas()
```

If I know want to put the data in a Modin df for parallel computations without having to write to and read from a csv? Is there a way to construct the Modin df directly from a pyarrow.Table or at least from a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Mahesh's answer should work but I believe it would result in a full data copy (2X memory footprint by default: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html#memory-usage-and-zero-copy)

At the time of writing Modin does have a native arrow integration, so you can directly convert using

```
from modin.pandas.utils import from_arrow

mdf = from_arrow(pyarrow_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't construct the Modin dataframe directly out of a `pyarrow.Table`, because pandas doesn't support that, and Modin only supports a subset of the pandas API. However, the table has a method that converts it to a pandas dataframe, and you can construct the Modin dataframe out of that. Using `table` from your code:

```py
import modin.pandas as pd
modin_dataframe = pd.Dataframe(table.to_pandas())
```